# What could be causing TPM_RC_COMMAND_SIZE error (0x80010000000a00000142) in response to TPM_GETRANDOM?

Tags: spi, bus, tpm, hardware-interface

I am encountering an issue while working with an Infineon SLB9670 TPM (Trusted Platform Module) using its SPI.

I am issuing the `TPM_GETRANDOM` command, and receiving the error code:

> `0x80010000000a00000142` (`TPM_RC_COMMAND_SIZE`)

The specific sequence of transactions leading to this error is as follows:

| Operation | mAddress | Size | data out | dataIn | miso out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| read | 0x0 | 1 | 0x81 |  |  |
| read | 0x0 | 1 | 0x81 |  |  |
| write | 0x0 | 1 |  | 0x02 | 0 |
| read | 0x0 | 1 | 0xA1 |  |  |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x40 |  |  |
| read | 0x19 | 1 | 0xFF |  |  |
| write | 0x24 | c |  | 0x80010000 000c0000 017b0010 | 0 0 0 0 **`0x80`** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x88 |  |  |
| write | 0x18 | 1 |  | 0x20 | 0 |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x90 |  |  |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x90 |  |  |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x90 |  |  |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x90 |  |  |
| read | 0x19 | 1 | 0x0A |  |  |
| read | 0x1a | 1 | 0x00 |  |  |
| read | 0x24 | a | **0x420100000A0000000180** |  |  |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x80 |  |  |
| read | 0x18 | 1 | 0x80 |  |  |
| write | 0x18 | 1 |  | 0x40 | 0 |
| write | 0x0 | 1 |  | 0x20 | 0 |
| read | 0x19 | 1 | 0xFF |  |  |
| read | 0x0 | 1 | 0x81 |  |  |

I'm having trouble pinpointing the root cause of this error. Could someone shed some light on what might be causing this `TPM_RC_COMMAND_SIZE` error?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: From TPM Lib. Part 2 rev.1.55  "command commandSize value is inconsistent with contents of the command buffer; either the size is not the same as the octets loaded by the hardware interface layer or the value is not large enough to hold a command header". It seems the sizes you send and buffered are different.

Comment: Size 16Byte (10 -it is hex) byte but dataIn is 10 Byte on 16th entry in the table.

Comment: I corrected the table, please see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you post the actual command stream, I can test it for you.

Or use a SW TPM to debug, e.g., https://github.com/kgoldman/ibmswtpm2.

On Windows, the MS Store has a command decoder that might help.